# GNU Makefile get directory names and concat string

Tags: string, makefile, directory, gnu-make, gnu

I need to write a makefile code that would get a list of all directories under a specific path and extract the dir name and concatenate it to a string.
What I have so far is

```
list-dir:
    for dir in $(wildcard mypath/*/); do \
        echo $$dir ; \
    done
```

However this returns a full dir path e.g.

```
mypath/a/
mypath/b/
mypath/c/
```

From here I need to be able to get a, b and c and concatenate them to foo- so what i need is

```
foo-a
foo-b
foo-c
```

Anything I try to do with the gnu functions, e.g. patsubst or basename the output is

```
list-dir:
    for dir in $(wildcard mypath/*/); do \
        echo $$dir ; \
        $(patsubst %\,,$$dir) ; \
    done
mypath/a/: is a directory
mypath/b/: is a directory
mypath/c/: is a directory
```

I don't understand what is not called correctly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result that you want is computable by `make` without the use of
any target or recipe:

**Makefile (1)**

```
DIRS := $(patsubst %,foo-%,$(notdir $(wildcard mypath/*)))
$(info $(DIRS))
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
foo-c foo-b foo-a
make: *** No targets. Stop.
```

Use the computed result in a recipe like this:

**Makefile (2)**

```
DIRS := $(patsubst %,foo-%,$(notdir $(wildcard mypath/*)))

.PHONY: all

all:
    echo $(DIRS)
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
echo foo-c foo-b foo-a
foo-c foo-b foo-a
```

Alternatively you could write a target with a recipe consisting
of shell script to output the result:

**Makefile (3)**

```
.PHONY: all

all:
    for d in $$(ls mypath); do \
        echo "foo-"$$d; \
    done
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
for d in $(ls mypath); do \
    echo "foo-"$d; \
done
foo-a
foo-b
foo-c
```

What you *can't* do is mix up the two ways of doing it. `make` has done its
`$(...)` evaluations before the recipe for any target is run. The recipe
that is run for any target, after all those `$(...)` evaluations are done,
consists of shell-commands, *only*. By the time your recipe:

```
list-dir:
    for dir in $(wildcard mypath/*/); do \
        echo $$dir ; \
        $(patsubst %\,,$$dir) ; \
    done
```

gets run, it is:

```
for dir in mypath/c/ mypath/b/ mypath/a/; do \
    echo $dir ; \
    $dir ; \
done
```

Which clearly will fail. And that is because `$(patsubst %\,,$$dir)` was evaluated by `make`
when it parsed the recipe and, since the make-expansion of `$$dir` is `$dir`, and there is
no match for `%\` in `$dir`, the whole `$(patsubst %\,,$$dir)` expression 
evaluates to `$dir`, and is replaced by `$dir` in the recipe.